# React is rendering FontAwesome Styles to page

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm able to render the various FontAwesome icons to my React App, but at the same time - on top of my page it is also rendering the raw css styles that comes with FontAwesome. If I inspect my page - I see a style element there with type=css. I believe I'm handling CSS files in my webpack with:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,  
    include: /node_modules/,  
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  },
```

Not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: How are you importing FontAwesome? Can you post `index.html`?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I'm importing FontAwesome via NPM Modules - then requiring them into my React Components.


`import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Font Awesome 5 SVG with JS](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js), then, by default, Font Awesome will automatically add its CSS the first time it renders an icon, unless you set `autoAddCss` to `false` in the config. You can see more about [setting the config options](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/font-awesome-api) here. To disable that, you could add a `<script>` block to set the config *before* loading the Font Awesome js, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoAddCss: false }
</script>
```

Or, like this within a JavaScript module that loads FontAwesome—*before* FontAwesome tries to render the first icon:

```
import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome";
fontawesome.config = { autoAddCss: false };
```

UPDATE: the above examples are *current* ways to do it, as of Font Awesome 5.0.x. With the release of 5.1, we'll have a different way to do it, which is documented in our [preview docs here](https://fontawesome.com/preview/how-to-use/font-awesome-api).

Comment: i'm using the FontAwesome React npm modules

Comment: The current release of `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` (`0.0.20`) disables autoAddCss for you. See here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/blob/7c5a660962db448a9efb29731611463f91428b35/index.es.js#L615

If you're still seeing CSS automatically added, I'd need to see a reproduction of that on CodeSandbox.io or somesuch in order to have enough context to troubleshoot.

Comment: here is a link to my repo in codesandbox - the only issue is none of my scss has loaded... from the main page add /goozgooz to the url to get to the page using fontawesome

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/goozgooz/sms-frontend/tree/master

Comment: I've made a mistake. I stand by my answer above (and I'll update it with more), but in my comment above I mistakenly said that `react-fontawesome` disables `autoAddCss` for you. It disables `autoReplaceSvg` and `observeMutations`, but not `autoAddCss`, so you have to do that yourself, if you want. This fork of your repro shows how: https://codesandbox.io/s/2p5r4w645n

Comment: that solved it. thank you for taking the time to sort that out!

Comment: Great! Glad it's working. In that case, could you go ahead and accept my answer?